# Get collection name from firebase document

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way I can get the name of the collection a Firestore document is stored in based off a variable of type `QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>`? I'm using Firebase v9.

Comment: What do you try to archive? most of the time when you receive a document you already know the collection to fetch it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.ref`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentsnapshot.md#documentsnapshotref) property of [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querydocumentsnapshot) to get that document's [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference.md) and get the collection reference by using [`.parent`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference.md#documentreferenceparent) as shown below:

```
const snap = "" // The QueryDocumentSnapshot

console.log("Collection name:", snap.ref.parent.id)
```

If that document is a part of sub-collection, then it'll log name of that sub-collection. You can chain `.ref.parent` again to get parent collection of the same.